# AngularJS Provider dependency injection - using $log in provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

**The problem** is simple: using AngularJS we can't inject $log into provider.

```
angular.module('my.module', [])
    .provider('myProvider', function ($log, $logProvider) {
        $log.log("Aloha!"); // Unknown provider: $log
        $logProvider.log("Hi!"); // undefined is not a function: $logProvider has no `log` method 
        this.$get = function($log) {
            $log.log("Hello!"); // Everything is ok here
        };
    });
```

Yes, we can inject `$logProvider`, but it has no needed methods(`.log`, `.error`, etc.).

Yes, we can inject `$logProvider`, and then manually call `$logProvider.$get()`, but we will unable to use additional logic from decorators.

Yes, we can write our own logProvider, but I wonder why Angular don't support this feature out-of-the-box.

So, we can't use console in 'true angular way' in provider? That fact is very strange. And sad.

**The question**: how I need to use console in "true Angular way" in providers?

I was unable to find any explanations of this problem.
Angular Developers Guide says that we need to use $log everywhere instead of console.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Providers run too early before any services are created or in other words provider's $get is the service constructor and it gets instantiated after the config phase of the module (and when it is accessed for the first time via dependency injection the injector instantiates the constructor and keep it as singleton). And providers run during or before the config phase (since the provider methods are used for configuring the service during the `config` phase of the module). Which means $log service is not available yet.

`$logProvider.$get` will give you the constructor for logservice, you could yourself create an instance of it by calling `$injector.instantiate($logProvider.$get)` but the problem is that it has a dependency on window service which has not bee instantiated yet, so ultimately your logger instantiation will fail.

So one way i could just think of is to get $log from another injector, i.e `angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log')`.

i.e

```
angular.module('my.module', [])
  .provider('myProvider', function ($log, $logProvider) {
    var $log =  angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log');
    $log.log("Aloha!"); 

    this.$get = function($log) {
        $log.log("Hello!"); // Everything is ok here
    };
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TXTc1U?p=preview)**

Or another way just go crazy instantiate it on your own, instantiating its dependent services in this case it is just the **$window** (or even provide **global window** object as locals).

```
 .provider('myProvider', function ($logProvider,$injector, $windowProvider) {
    //get window service, if you want to really provide window service instance itself, or just provide the global window object
    var window = $injector.instantiate($windowProvider.$get);
    //Get log provider providing locals for $window
    var $log =  $injector.instantiate($logProvider.$get,{$window:window})

    $log.log("Aloha!");// Everything is ok here too

    this.$get = function($log) {
        $log.log("Hello!"); // Everything is ok here
    };

});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTNlzp?p=preview)**

Just to add a different note: You will see the same behavior while trying to access the `$log` service during the config phase of the app as well. But sometimes due to the way `decorators` work you could still make use of it by forcing an early service creation by using a dummy decorator.

i.e:

```
.config(function($provide){
   //Just a dummy decorator
   $provide.decorator('$log', function($delegate){
      return $delegate;
  });

}).config(function($logProvider){
   //get logger instance
   var log = $logProvider.$get();
   log.debug("Got it");
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/moICKG?p=preview)**

So ultimately the idea is that, when you need to use a service before it has been instantiated yet, you would need to manually instantiate it by resolving all of its dependencies and so on.

Comment: Just to add to that, that this `$log` will be a different instance than the one that would be injected into the app. With `$log` it may not matter, but if it was a different service, it could

Comment: @PSL, `angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log')` is a nice solution! (we still loose logic from custom decorators, but I'm make up mind to this sad fact). But you don't answer my question. I think user **should** be able to use $log(or something) in providers and config sections. You think there is no 'true Angular' solution for this problem? Something like native Angular.log() method.

Comment: @harryburns Frankly i neved had to do much logging inside those blocks. If at all use console.log.. any way u cannot really make use of di by injecting $log service itself out there so what is the point.. and there are no static log functions available in angular.

Comment: @PSL, Well. At last chance I will stop on solution with my own logProvider, which is accessible from config sections and other providers. It's cleaner than use console.log directly. Thanks for help!

Comment: Whoa, such an easy thing and so many words. Angular truly is a horrible world at times.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper service say logger which can have methods like log, warn, debug etc. and inject your logger service wherever required you can do the formatting there

eg: 
Below method is inside my logger service to invoke this just inject logger and call log method.

```
this.log = function () {
        if (this.debuggingEnabled) {
           for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              $log.log("[" + $filter('date')(new Date(), this.format) + "] -- " + arguments[0] + " -- " + JSON.stringify(arguments[i]));
           }
        }
     };
```