# Can we do logging in .config inside application module in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

So I was trying to inject $log in config() module in application.ts

```
.config(['$log',($log: angular.ILogService): void => { ...} // Unknown provider: $log
```

Can we inject dependencies in config() like this? What am I doing wrong?

Read this post : [AngularJS Provider dependency injection - using $log in provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620927/angularjs-provider-dependency-injection-using-log-in-provider) but it's about injection Dependencies using provider